How to Create Collections in Strapi and Relate Them to External API Data?
I have a requirement to create collections in Strapi, specifically a "Products" collection, where each product is related to multiple services. However, these services come from an external API, not directly from Strapi.
How can I display these external services when creating products in Strapi, and how do I establish the relationship between products and these external services?
Here's what I need to achieve:

Create a "Products" collection in Strapi.
Fetch services from an external API.
Display these external services in the Strapi admin panel while creating or editing a product.
Establish and maintain the relationship between products and these external services.

What I have tried so far:

I have successfully created the "Products" collection in Strapi.
I have written a script to fetch services from the external API and can log the data in the console.

I am now looking for the best way to integrate these external services into the Strapi admin panel so they can be selected when creating or editing products. Any guidance or examples would be highly appreciated.

Strapi supports custom controllers and is quite impressive. Here it is in the docs :
Strapi custom controllers
Last project I finished required custom Strapi controllers. Here is how I did it :

Challenge : Now comes the challenging part that is how to integrate/display the external services into the Strapi admin panel UI. As far as my knowledge, Strapi supports writing Business logic through custom controllers but won't display/entertain these logic/services on its Admin Panel UI unless its Strapi plugins.
Possible Solution : What I think is you can add some key as flag in Products collection and in the code apply the logics on basis of that. Here is the pseudodcode :
async find(ctx) {
    const user = ctx.state.user;

    function transformData(inputData) {

      if(inputData.keyFlag){
        return {
          data: inputData.map(item => ({
            country: externalSource.name
          }))
        };

      }else{

        return {
          data: inputData.map(item => ({
            price: externalSource.price
          }))
        };

      }

    
    }

    const dataValue = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::plan.plan");

    let outputData=[]
    if(dataValue?.length>0){
      outputData = transformData(dataValue);
    }

    return  outputData ;
  }

I hope this helps. Corrections welcomed!
